# How do I set names for "sections" for renderdoc to show?

Tags: renderdoc

E.g. I want all GL calls between point A and point B to be nested in a section called "Gaussianblur" in RenderDoc.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here:

https://renderdoc.org/docs/window/event_browser.html

> glPushDebugGroupKHR(GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_APPLICATION, 0, -1, "Begin
>   Section");
>
> // contents of section here
>
> glPopDebugGroupKHR();